# Однородные или неоднородные определения: "солидные (,) опытные российские организации"

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

В последние два года «скороспелки» в целом по России на 80 % вытеснили за счет демпинга солидные (,) опытные российские организации с рынка проектных услуг.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что запятая не нужна, поскольку здесь выражаются разные признаки, а именно: степень солидности и степень опытности. Согласно представленному [перечню](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) значений слова, мы не можем считать слово *солидный* за синоним слова *опытный*. Если посмотреть с другой стороны, весь этот ряд является характеристикой, а такое явление в некоторых случаях, насколько я знаю, обособляется.

Comment: Значит нет однозначного ответа... Спасибо большое.

Comment: А еще после «значит» нужна запятая. :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так и так трактовать. Это целиком вкусовщина авторская, фраза в целом неудачна стилистически, понять трудно, характеризуют ли с одной стороны или с разных.

Но я бы запятую поставил, пусть будут однородными, это всегда проще объяснить.

А еще вернее - написал бы через союз и не мучился.

***В последние два года «скороспелки» в целом по России на 80% вытеснили за счет демпинга солидные и опытные российские организации с рынка проектных услуг.***

Ну а если еще и стиль править, то все поменять местами.

***В целом по России за последние два года «скороспелки» за счет демпинга на 80% вытеснили с рынка проектных услуг солидные и опытные российские организации.***

Уже лучше смотрится, хотя можно и дальше.

Comment: Спасибо большое.